# How to generate a xml or json mapping from xls file and then generate html table(structure) from that mapping?

Tags: java, xml, json, excel, apache-poi

I need to read a `xls` file and generate a mapping from it. My `xls` file is structured and formatted (for eg: like a report). Mapping can be in any form say `JSON` or `xml`. From Mapping I mean the information of all cells (what type of information they are storing). Once the mapping is generated then I have to create a html structure say table from the generated mapping.

Please suggest something. I can use any Excel Java API.

Comment: It's Java, not JAVA and it doesn't have to appear in the title if it's tagged.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use:

- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for reading the file
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for writing a JSON file

They are both mainstream and easy to use.